# How to remove unsupported ARPlaneAnchor.Classification enum cases when running on iOS 12?

Tags: ios, swift, enums, arkit, availability

Apple [announced](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/604/?time=2521) that with ARKit 3 (iOS 13), `ARPlaneAnchor.Classification` is getting two new values:

[image]

My project is targeting iOS 12.1.

I have the following code in my app:

```
extension ARPlaneAnchor.Classification {
    var description: String {
        switch self {
        case .wall:
            return "Wall"
        case .floor:
            return "Floor"
        case .ceiling:
            return "Ceiling"
        case .table:
            return "Table"
        case .seat:
            return "Seat"
        case .window:
            return "Window"
        case .door:
            return "Door"
        case .none(.unknown):
            return "Unknown"
        default:
            return ""
        }
    }
}
```

When I attempt to run it on an iPhone X running iOS 13, it runs just fine and executes the code path for `window` and `door`.

When I attempt to run it on an iPhone 8 running iOS 12.4, it crashes upon startup:

> dyld: Symbol not found: _$sSo13ARPlaneAnchorC5ARKitE14ClassificationO4dooryA2EmFWC
>    Referenced from: /var/containers/Bundle/Application/...
>    Expected in: /usr/lib/swift/libswiftARKit.dylib
>   in /var/containers/Bundle/Application/...

*Keywords for search: ARPlaneAnchor ARKit Classification door*

If I comment out the `case door` and `case window` it runs just fine.

This is obviously a bug in that the enum cases for `door` and `window` are only available on iOS 13.

When I command-click the definition, I see that Apple defined it as so:

```
/**
 A value describing the classification of a plane anchor.
 */
@available(iOS 12.0, *)
public enum __ARPlaneClassification : Int {


    /** The classification is not any of the known classes. */
    case none

    /** The classification is not any of the known classes. */
    case wall

    /** The classification is not any of the known classes. */
    case floor

    /** The classification is not any of the known classes. */
    case ceiling

    /** The classification is not any of the known classes. */
    case table

    /** The classification is not any of the known classes. */
    case seat

    /** The classification is not any of the known classes. */
    case window

    /** The classification is not any of the known classes. */
    case door
}
```

or sometimes it looks like this:

```
@available(iOS 12.0, *)
extension ARPlaneAnchor {

    public enum Classification {

        // ...

        /** The classification is not any of the known classes. */
        case none(ARPlaneAnchor.Classification.Status)

        case wall

        case floor

        case ceiling

        case table

        case seat

        case window

        case door
    }

    public var classification: ARPlaneAnchor.Classification { get }
}
```

As you can see in both examples, a new iOS 13 enum (e.g. `door`) appears exactly the same as an older iOS 12 enum (e.g. `wall`). I believe this is what causes it to compile just fine but crash on startup.

How do I get the code to run just fine on both devices running iOS 13 and those running iOS 12?

---

**Update**: I tried to use an [availability check](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/new-syntax-swift-2-availability-checking) such as:

```
extension ARPlaneAnchor.Classification {
    var description: String {
        if #available(iOS 13, *) {
            return description_13()
        } else {
            return description_12()
        }
    }

    @available(iOS 12, *)
    private func description_12() -> String {
        switch self {
        case .wall:
            return "Wall"
        case .floor:
            return "Floor"
        case .ceiling:
            return "Ceiling"
        case .table:
            return "Table"
        case .seat:
            return "Seat"
        case .none(.unknown):
            return "Unknown"
        default:
            return ""
        }
    }

    @available(iOS 13, *)
    private func description_13() -> String {
        switch self {
        case .window:
            return "Window"
        case .door:
            return "Door"
        default:
            return description_12()
        }
    }
}
```

However, this produced the same exact "Symbol not found" error as before. Any suggestions for how to get this to work?

Comment: I was running into this as well.
It appears that, while .door and .window are listed as available in iOS 12, they aren't actually in the libswiftARKit.dylib until iOS 13.
I believe this to be an Apple bug.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem and I ended up with reflection. Not nice but seems work well.

```
extension ARPlaneAnchor.Classification {
    var description: String {
        switch self {
        case .wall:
            return "Wall"
        case .floor:
            return "Floor"
        case .ceiling:
            return "Ceiling"
        case .table:
            return "Table"
        case .seat:
            return "Seat"
        case .none(.unknown):
            return "Unknown"
        default:
          return description_13 ?? ""
        }
    }

    private var description_13: String? {
        let reflection = String(reflecting: self)
        let components = reflection.components(separatedBy: ".")
        switch components.last {
        case "window":
            return "Window"
        case "door":
            return "Door"
        default:
            return nil
        }
    }
}
```